# How to install twisted 10.2.0 with pypy 1.4.1?

Tags: python, twisted, pypy

I can't install twisted 10.2.0 to my ubuntu box. After download twisted source I issue the command: pypy setup.py install. After that I receive the error:

```
building 'twisted.runner.portmap' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.5
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.5/twisted
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.5/twisted/runner
cc -I/builds/pypy-1.4.1-linux64/include -c twisted/runner/portmap.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.5/twisted/runner/portmap.o
cc -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.5/twisted/runner/portmap.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.5/twisted/runner/portmap.pypy-14.so
/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.5/twisted/runner/portmap.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.5/twisted/runner/portmap.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

So, how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you need to install the `cc` program

Comment: Can you maybe reformat error message so people can read it? Otherwise it's easy to say "install c compiler".

Answer (score 4):

That's a "bug" in twisted build. It might be or might not be a bug - twisted does not consider it's C extensions optional, although they're far from necessary for the most part. Twisted would still work if you just point PYTHONPATH to where it is situated, but without those C extensions.

Comment: psh, Twisted considers them optional.  But good luck convincing distutils of anything.

Comment: ah well. zope.interface manages :) Not sure if manages in a good way though.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to skip building extensions by commenting off [the following line in setup.py (73)](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-10.2.0/setup.py#L73):

```
       conditionalExtensions = getExtensions(),
```

This should avoid collecting and trying to build extensions scattered in the directory tree.

Comment: This worked beautifully for me with Twisted 11.0 after my first attempt threw an error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As for now Twisted trunk could be compiled OK with PyPy (I used 1.6.1-dev0). 
However in order to install Twisted you'd need to apply a [patch](http://bugs.python.org/issue13133) to zipfile.py that I have submitted to stdlib.

zipfile.py 2.7.1+ leaks file descriptors because of CPython-oriented programming style used in zipfile.py

Therefore installation fails under PyPy that uses other GC model than CPython does.